# Bundle custom static files in meteor

Tags: meteor

I'd like to bundle many static files from various dirs in a meteor appplication. I have a different folders structure than the standard prescribed. I have static files in various directories and I serve them using the `webapp`. This works in dev on my machine where I access them directly by a path from `C:\...`. But when the app is bundled those files will not make it to the bundle. Is there any way how to tell meteor that it should also bundle those directories?

I try to achieve an encapsulation of modules. So each module would have its own static files and each would be a pack of all source and static files needed to run within an app. The static files need to be inside app folders. I have a `Modules` dir where are modules like `Users` and `Notes` and each of the modules can have its own static files which would be accessed by url and later by node fs, but they are not imported by js. That's why they'll not get into the bundle.

The files are consumed by

```js
const realpath = path.normalize(base + filepath);
const data = fs.readFileSync(realpath);
res.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": mime.lookup(realpath) });
res.write(data);
res.end();
```

Where `filepath` is calculated by function from url.

I explicitly don't want to use `public` folder or any folder of standard meteor folder structure. I have defined custom folder structure with idea of encapsulation in mind. I'm aware of `api.addAssets(filenames, architecture)` but that's only for packages AFAIK. But that's something as I'd need I guess. I'd expect that there would be possibility to write some script that would run while bundling and would provide information for bundler which files to include.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using meteor's /private directory would prevent any public access, and allow you to bundle your application code.

Comment: Yeah, making a symlink of `Modules` dir to `private` helps.